# How to use system calls with c++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, system-calls, cout

What I need to do is mimic std::cout using system calls.

I have seen the syscall() function that uses a number for the system call, the system() function that uses a string with a command and system_call() that worked for someone here in stackoverflow but she didn't list header files or anything so it didn't work for me.

I don't expect you to code it for me, since this is a homework, but I would like some clues as to which is the best way to go around it, what header files to use and functions to use and look into with more depth. I don't know the differences between those functions but ideally I would like to find c++11 functions.

I have only found vague information about those functions so I haven't been able to put any code together.

Comment: Since this is homework, is there a particular reason you didn't ask your teacher/lecturer this exact same question? Did you miss the class?

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: I'm in linux. Specifically raspbian. I didn't miss the class. I'm just trying to get it done today. Since it's sunday didn't want to bother the teacher. I thought I could post the question here and get some help since I didn't find anything helpful online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System calls, like API, are Operating System (OS) specific.

To use the API, you will need to include the appropriate header file and link with the appropriate libraries for your system.

Again, the C++ language does not cover platform specific functionality and you will need to search the web to find the API for your platform.

Comment: forgot to mention that. I'm in linux. specifically raspbian.

Answer (score 3):

> What I need to do is mimic std::cout using system calls.

You want to call the system call `write(2)` which is system call number 4, on the standard output file descriptor which is file descriptor 1.

Read:

```
$ man 2 syscall
$ man 2 syscalls
$ man 2 write
```